# Jenkins: Pipeline sh bad substitution error

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

A step in my pipeline uploads a .tar to an artifactory server. I am getting a Bad substitution error when passing in env.BUILD_NUMBER, but the same commands works when the number is hard coded. The script is written in groovy through jenkins and is running in the jenkins workspace.

```
sh 'curl -v --user user:password --data-binary ${buildDir}package${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.tar -X PUT "http://artifactory.mydomain.com/artifactory/release-packages/package${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.tar"'
```

returns the errors:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[Package_Deploy_Pipeline] Running shell script
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Package_Deploy_Pipeline@tmp/durable-4c8b7958/script.sh: 2: 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Package_Deploy_Pipeline@tmp/durable-4c8b7958/script.sh: Bad substitution
[Pipeline] } //node
[Pipeline] Allocate node : End
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 2
```

If hard code in a build number and swap out `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` I get no errors and the code runs successfully.

```
sh 'curl -v --user user:password --data-binary ${buildDir}package113.tar -X PUT "http://artifactory.mydomain.com/artifactory/release-packages/package113.tar"'
```

I use ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} within other sh commands within the same script and have no issues in any other places.

Comment: My guess is that `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` is being replaced by a pre-processing step before it is actually seen by shell in the other instances. `sh` itself is rightly treating it as an error.

Comment: in the same function right before this line im using ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} in the exact same way to upload to Google storage and thats giving me no issues.
EDIT: I also made a dummy variable and set it to a number then passed in the variable and got the same issue.

Comment: You may well be using the wrong quotes around the whole thing http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/groovy-goodness-string-strings-strings.html. Also you don't need to quote the URL for curl. So maybe using double quotes around the whole thing will work without any single quotes

Comment: Please show the *exact* code that uses `${env.BUILD_NUMER}` without a problem, because the error is the expected behavior for such a parameter expansion.

Comment: You lead me down the right path, it was the single quotes that were preventing env.BUILD_NUMBER from passing its value.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

This turned out to be a syntax issue. Wrapping the command in `'`'s caused `${env.BUILD_NUMBER` to be passed instead of its value. I wrapped the whole command in `"`s and escaped the nested. Works fine now.

```
sh "curl -v --user user:password --data-binary ${buildDir}package${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.tar -X PUT \"http://artifactory.mydomain.com/artifactory/release-packages/package${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.tar\""
```

Comment: Yea you nailed it, thanks for all the help. I missed your original comment somehow though, wish I would have read it sooner.

Comment: Not directly related to this issue, but please consider using the Artifactpry Pipeline DSL. It provides a more convenient Groovy DSL than curl cmd executions, reducing the chance for syntax mistakes: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+-+Working+With+the+Pipeline+Jenkins+Plugin

Comment: @BW use """ """

Comment: As long as any variables in the URL get substituted by Groovy and not by the shell, you can use single quotes instead of escaped double quotes around the URL.

Comment: in triple single [' ' '] quotes it throws bad substitution error, but after using triple [" " "] it works with variables like `${env.WORKSPACE}`.

Answer (score 55):

In order to **Pass groovy parameters into bash scripts in Jenkins pipelines** (causing sometimes bad substitions) **You got 2 options**:

> The **triple double quotes way [ " " " ]** 
>   OR
>   the **triple single quotes way [ ' ' ' ]**

1. **In triple double quotes** you can render the normal parameter from groovy using `${someVariable}` ,if it's environment variable `${env.someVariable}` , if it's parameters injected into your job `${params.someVariable}`

**example**:

```
     def YOUR_APPLICATION_PATH= "${WORKSPACE}/myApp/"

      sh """#!/bin/bash
      cd ${YOUR_APPLICATION_PATH}
      npm install
      """
```

2. **In triple single quotes** things getting little bit tricky, you *can pass the parameter to environment parameter* and using it by `"\${someVaraiable}"` *or concating the groovy parameter using* `''' + someVaraiable + '''`

**examples**:

```
   def YOUR_APPLICATION_PATH= "${WORKSPACE}/myApp/"

   sh '''#!/bin/bash
          cd ''' + YOUR_APPLICATION_PATH + '''
          npm install
    '''
```

OR

```
   pipeline{
     agent { node { label "test" } }
     environment {
       YOUR_APPLICATION_PATH = "${WORKSPACE}/myapp/"
     }

     continue...
     continue...
     continue...

     sh '''#!/bin/bash
          cd "\${YOUR_APPLICATION_PATH}"
          npm install
    '''

    //OR
    sh '''#!/bin/bash
          cd "\${env.YOUR_APPLICATION_PATH}"
          npm install
    '''
```

Comment: is escaping (\$) really needed in te triple single quotes sample?

Comment: Thank you for explaining properly with examples. Helped a lot, was stuck for hours

Answer (score 28):

Actually, you seem to have misunderstood the `env` variable. In your `sh` block, you should access `${BUILD_NUMBER}` directly.

**Reason/Explanation:** `env` represents the environment inside the script. This environment is used/available directly to anything that is executed, e.g. shell scripts.

Please also pay attention to not write anything to `env.*`, but use `withEnv{}` blocks instead.

Comment: This is the decent answer!

Comment: perfect hint. Should solve the problem in most cases.

Answer (score 23):

Usually the most common issue for:

> Bad substitution

error is to use `sh` instead of `bash`.

Especially when using Jenkins, if you're using *Execute shell*, make sure your *Command* starts with *[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))*, e.g. `#!/bin/bash -xe` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: That's definitely the cause, but if you need to use `sh` what is the solution?

Answer (score 13):

I can definitely tell you, it's all about sh shell and bash shell. I fixed this problem by specifying `#!/bin/bash -xe` as follows:

```
node {
    stage("Preparing"){
        sh'''#!/bin/bash -xe
            colls=( col1 col2 col3 )
            for eachCol in ${colls[@]}
            do
              echo $eachCol
            done
        '''
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue when working on a **Jenkins** Pipeline for **Amazon S3** Application upload.

My script was like this:

```
pipeline {  
  agent any
  parameters {
    string(name: 'Bucket', defaultValue: 's3-pipeline-test', description: 'The name of the Amazon S3 Bucket')
    string(name: 'Prefix', defaultValue: 'my-website', description: 'Application directory in the Amazon S3 Bucket')
    string(name: 'Build', defaultValue: 'public/', description: 'Build directory for the application')
  }  
  stages {  
    stage('Build') {  
      steps {
        echo 'Running build phase'
        sh 'npm install' // Install packages
        sh 'npm run build' // Build project 
        sh 'ls' // List project files
      }  
    }  
    stage('Deploy') {  
      steps {  
        echo 'Running deploy phase'
        withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: 'AWSCredentials', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) { 
          sh 'aws s3 ls' // List AWS S3 buckets
          sh 'aws s3 sync "${params.Build}" s3://"${params.Bucket}/${params.Prefix}" --delete' // Sync project files with AWS S3 Bucket project path
        }  
      }   
    }
  }
  post { 
    success {  
      echo 'Deployment to Amazon S3 suceeded'  
    }  
    failure {  
      echo 'Deployment to Amazon S3 failed'  
    }  
  }  
}
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Seeing that it's an interpolation call of variables, I had to substitute the single quotation marks (**' '**) in this line of the script:

```
sh 'aws s3 sync "${params.Build}" s3://"${params.Bucket}/${params.Prefix}" --delete' // Sync project files with AWS S3 Bucket project path
```

to double quotation marks (**" "**):

```
sh "aws s3 sync ${params.Build} s3://${params.Bucket}/${params.Prefix} --delete" // Sync project files with AWS S3 Bucket project path
```

So my script looked like this afterwards:

```
pipeline {  
  agent any
  parameters {
    string(name: 'Bucket', defaultValue: 's3-pipeline-test', description: 'The name of the Amazon S3 Bucket')
    string(name: 'Prefix', defaultValue: 'my-website', description: 'Application directory in the Amazon S3 Bucket')
    string(name: 'Build', defaultValue: 'public/', description: 'Build directory for the application')
  }  
  stages {  
    stage('Build') {  
      steps {
        echo 'Running build phase'
        sh 'npm install' // Install packages
        sh 'npm run build' // Build project 
        sh 'ls' // List project files
      }  
    }  
    stage('Deploy') {  
      steps {  
        echo 'Running deploy phase'
        withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: 'AWSCredentials', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) { 
          sh 'aws s3 ls' // List AWS S3 buckets
          sh "aws s3 sync ${params.Build} s3://${params.Bucket}/${params.Prefix} --delete" // Sync project files with AWS S3 Bucket project path
        }  
      }   
    }
  }
  post { 
    success {  
      echo 'Deployment to Amazon S3 suceeded'  
    }  
    failure {  
      echo 'Deployment to Amazon S3 failed'  
    }  
  }  
}
```

That's all

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 2):

I was having the issue with showing the `{env.MAJOR_VERSION}` in an artifactory of jar file . show I approaches by keeping of environment step in Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline {
agent any
environment {
MAJOR_VERSION = 1
}

stages {
stage('build') {
  steps {
      sh 'ant -f build.xml -v'
 }
}
}
post {
 always{
   archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'dist/*.jar', fingerprint: true
 }
}
}
```

I got the issue solved and then it was not showing me bad substitution in my Jenkins build output. so environment step plays a more role in Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 2):

This caused the error **Bad Substitution**:

```
pipeline {
     agent any

     environment {
        DOCKER_IMAGENAME = "mynginx:latest"
        DOCKER_FILE_PATH = "./docker"
     }
  
     stages {
         stage('DockerImage-Build') {
            steps {
             sh 'docker build -t ${env.DOCKER_IMAGENAME} ${env.DOCKER_FILE_PATH}'
            }
         }             
     }
 }
```

This fixed it: replace **'** with **"** on sh command

```
    pipeline {
     agent any

     environment {
        DOCKER_IMAGENAME = "mynginx:latest"
        DOCKER_FILE_PATH = "./docker"
     }
  
     stages {
         stage('DockerImage-Build') {
            steps {
             sh "docker build -t ${env.DOCKER_IMAGENAME} ${env.DOCKER_FILE_PATH}"
            }
         }             
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

suggestion from @avivamg didn't worked for me, here is the syntax which works for me:

```
 sh "python3 ${env.WORKSPACE}/package.py --product productname " +
    "--build_dir ${release_build_dir} " +
    "--signed_product_dir ${signed_product_dir} " +
    "--version ${build_version}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue. But my usecase is little different

```
            steps{
                sh '''#!/bin/bash -xe
                      VAR=TRIAL
                      echo $VAR
                      if [ -d /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/'\${params.application_name}' ]
                      then
                        echo 'working'
                        echo ${VAR}
                      else
                        echo 'not working'
                      fi
                      
                      
            '''
            }
        }
```

here I'm trying to declare a variable inside the script and also use a parameter from outside

After trying multiple ways

The following script worked

```
stage('cleaning com/avizva directory'){
            steps{
                sh """#!/bin/bash -xe
                      VAR=TRIAL
                      echo \$VAR
                      if [ -d /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/${params.application_name} ]
                      then
                        echo 'working'
                        echo \${VAR}
                      else
                        echo 'not working'
                      fi
                      
                      
            """
            }
        }
```

changes made :

Replaced triple single quotes --> triple double quotes

Whenever I want to refer to local variable I used escape character
$VAR --> `\$VAR`

Answer (score -1):

The Jenkins Script is failing inside the "sh" command-line E.g:

```
sh 'npm run build' <-- Fails referring to package.json
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
sh 'npm run ng build....'
```

... ng $PATH is not found by the package.json.