# How to tell Jenkins to keep temporary durable sh tasks?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Sometimes I get errors from inside the durable tasks but I was not able to find a way to make Jenkins disable the removal of these scripts.

When it happens I see something like: `/home/j/workspace/jobname/subjidr@tmp/durable-a209d793/script.sh: line 32: <some error>`

I need to be able to keep these files in order to see what went wrong, or at least to print their content on the console before running them.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Having a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219348/jenkins-pipeline-sh-bad-substitution), you might have a look to variable replacement in your command line.

ie : ${MY_VAR} that could contain null value or special character.