# Get list of branches in Jenkins multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees, jenkins-blueocean

The Blue Ocean interface to a Jenkins multibranch pipeline project shows several branches that were automatically created.

Is there a programmatic way to list the branches in the pipeline from code to be added to a Jenkinsfile?

This question asks about Jenkins Project branch information located inside the Jenkins application object model, which should be accessible via the Jenkins API or CLI.

I looked at all the variables that are available at `http://<jenkins-home>/env-vars.html/` , but none of those variables seem to describe the information that I seek.

The list of project branches is clearly available to the Multibranch project.  What syntax is required in order for the list of branches to be extracted into a script that runs in a `Jenkinsfile`?

### @bto's suggestions

I tried `@bto`'s suggestion, but I am getting an error indicating that an unexpected `(` has been found.

Here is the relevant minimal `Jenkinsfile` that produces the new error:

```
node {
    // Clean workspace before doing anything
    deleteDir()

    try {
        stage ('Clone') {
            sh '''
                project = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(env.JOB_NAME.minus("/${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}"))
                    project.getItems().each { job ->
                        println job.getProperty(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.BranchJobProperty.class).getBranch().getName()
                    }
            '''
        }
    } catch (err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
        throw err
    }
}
```

And here is the log file containing the error:

```
 project = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(env.JOB_NAME.minus("/${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}")) project.getItems().each { job -> println job.getProperty(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.BranchJobProperty.class).getBranch().getName() }— Shell Script<1s
    [ne_GWS-43-getissueforcommit-M2X23QGNMETLDZWFK7IXVZQRCNSWYNTDFJZU54VP7DMIOD6Z4DGA] Running shell script
    /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ne_GWS-43-getissueforcommit-M2X23QGNMETLDZWFK7IXVZQRCNSWYNTDFJZU54VP7DMIOD6Z4DGA@tmp/durable-27d568b1/script.sh: line 3: syntax error: unexpected "("
    script returned exit code 2
```

**Second Approach**

Alternatively, I removed the enclosing `sh """ ... """` block, per `@bto`'s comment, but this produced a different error about `No Steps`.

The confusion may be due to this being a 'scripted pipeline' and not a 'declarative pipeline'. See the difference between 'declarative' and scripted pipelines [at this link](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/).

Here is the alternative minimal `Jenkinsfile`.

```
node {
    // Clean workspace before doing anything
    deleteDir()

    try {
        stage ('Clone') {
            project = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(env.JOB_NAME.minus("/${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}"))
                project.getItems().each { job ->
                    println job.getProperty(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.BranchJobProperty.class).getBranch().getName()
                }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
        throw err
    }
}
```

And here is the log that results from the alternative approach:

```
No steps    This stage has no steps

    Branch event
    Obtained Jenkinsfile from 35adc9e931b45b1d1b3ace17c8fbddeeb5471ee1
    Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
    [Pipeline] node
    Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ne_GWS-43-getissueforcommit-M2X23QGNMETLDZWFK7IXVZQRCNSWYNTDFJZU54VP7DMIOD6Z4DGA
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] deleteDir
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (Clone)
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    [Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
    [Bitbucket] Build result notified
    an exception which occurred:
        in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
        in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@739b5db2
        in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
        in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@1ca5a320
        in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@1ca5a320
    Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(LinkedHashMap.java:333)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:273)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.SerializableScript.writeObject(SerializableScript.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor147.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:273)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
        at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:273)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$0(RiverWriter.java:144)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:477)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:453)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:440)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:367)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Finished: FAILURE
```

**Isolating The Error:**

If I reduce `@bto`'s suggested code to the following three lines, I can then turn the error off by commenting out the second of the following three lines, and then turn the error back on again by uncommenting the second line.  Therefore, the line of code that causes the `Java.ip.NonSerializableException` is `project.getItems()`, as follows:

```
project = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(env.JOB_NAME.minus("/${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}"))
//project.getItems()
project = null
```

Note that I also needed to add `project = null`.

**Problem Adding Exceptions:**

When I try to deploy `@bto`'s suggested `Jenkinsfile`, the following error is shown in the Jenkins Blue Ocean interface:

[image: Jenkins_Error.jpg]

But nothing happens when I click in any location on the error message.

Then I open a separate window to access the Jenkins tool for adding security exceptions, but nothing is queued up for automatic approval, and nothing allows me to manually enter the commands that need to be approved.  What I get is the following screen:

[image: Jenkins_Exceptions.jpg]

Scrolling down to the bottom of the screen shown in the image does not reveal anything new.

**Another attempt to whitelist:**

Per `@bto`'s comment, I went to `http://<jenkins-home>/script` and entered the following, and then clicked the **Run** button:

```
def getBranchNames(project){
    project.getItems().each { job ->
        echo job.getProperty(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.BranchJobProperty.class).getBranch().getName()
    }
}
getBranchNames(jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("my-project-name-string"))
```

But the following error was generated, and NOTHING was added to the approval queue at `http://<jenkins-home>/scriptApproval`:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.echo() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [GWS-43-getissueforcommit]
Possible solutions: each(groovy.lang.Closure), getAt(java.lang.String), wait(), run(), run(), every()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at Script1$_getBranchNames_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:3)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2040)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2025)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2066)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at Script1.getBranchNames(Script1.groovy:2)
    at Script1$getBranchNames.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:6)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:142)
    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:114)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(RemotingDiagnostics.java:111)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins._doScript(Jenkins.java:4331)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doScript(Jenkins.java:4302)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:225)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:61)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What else must be changed in order to resolve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to need to whitelist* a lot of method signatures to get this to work, but you should be able to do something like:

```
@NonCPS
def getBranchNames(project){
    project.getItems().each { job ->
        echo job.getProperty(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.BranchJobProperty.class).getBranch().getName()
    }
}

node {
    // Clean workspace before doing anything
    deleteDir()
    stage ('Clone') {
        getBranchNames(jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(env.JOB_NAME.minus("/${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}")))
        echo "done reading jobs"
    }
}
```

Note that this snippet excludes the `try`/`catch` error handling from the original request: By catching the whitelist exceptions, they aren't correctly added to the scriptApproval list. *After* it makes it through with no whitelist exceptions, you can add the error handling back in, as follows:

```
@NonCPS
def getBranchNames(project){
    project.getItems().each { job ->
        echo job.getProperty(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.BranchJobProperty.class).getBranch().getName()
    }
}

node {
    // Clean workspace before doing anything
    deleteDir()
    try {
        stage ('Clone') {
            getBranchNames(jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(env.JOB_NAME.minus("/${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}")))
            echo "done reading jobs"
        }
    } catch (err) {
        error "BUILD FAILED: ${err}"
    }
}
```

* Whitelisting happens through `http://<jenkins-home>/scriptApproval`. I basically ran my test job, looked at the console output failure, clicked the approval link, and "approved" the item in question. I had to whitelist the following to get this to work:

- `staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance`'

  - Caveat! This one is flagged out as potentially introducing a security vulnerability (since it lets scripts get their hands on the Jenkins instance)
- `method hudson.model.ItemGroup getItem java.lang.String`
- `method hudson.model.ItemGroup getItems`
- `method hudson.model.Job getProperty java.lang.Class`
- `method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.BranchJobProperty getBranch`
- `method jenkins.branch.Branch getName`

Comment: I just put the results of my attempt to implement your suggestions into a separate section at the end of the OP.  Note that the `No Steps` error first appeared when I simply pasted your suggestion into the top of the `Jenkinsfile`, and that I then subsequently made a first attempt to resolve the `No Steps` error by encasing your suggestion into a multi-line shell command, as shown above.  What do you suggest now?

Comment: Changed variable names; should avoid the `it` issue now. Also fixed how it gets the branch name.

Comment: Your edit enabled me to isolate that `staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance` now needs to be whitelisted, so I am googling how to whitelist a method.  So far, I have only gotten as far as reading [this link](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/).

Comment: I updated the **`@bto`'s Suggestions** section of the OP to include the current error that your suggestion is throwing related to an unexpected `(`.  What else must be changed?

Comment: Does your suggestion require the `Jenkinsfile` to specify which shell should be used in the command? If so, which shell?  This is running on CentOS 7.  I am reading the answers to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219348/jenkins-pipeline-sh-bad-substitution), and it seems that in some cases specifying the shell can alter the behavior of `sh` commands in `Jenkinsfile`s.

Comment: The code I posted is standalone groovy and shouldn't be wrapped in an `sh` block. I'll try to pay an improved version this evening.

Comment: I just added a section at the end of the OP showing the result of removing the enclosing `sh """ ... """`.  This may be related to the difference between a `Declarative Pipeline` and a `Scripted Pipeline`.  I am researching this currently, but I am new to Jenkins, so this takes me a long time.  Your insights are appreciated.  I just want a working minimal Jenkinsfile to resolve this error so that I can keep moving and learn in working increments.

Comment: You're right, it's scripted vs declarative. My apologies for not picking up on that from the first error message. Still planning on getting a better example together!

Comment: Noting the `java.io.NonSerializableException`, I have been experimenting with [the code in this example](https://gist.github.com/oifland/ab56226d5f0375103141b5fbd7807398), but so far have not experienced any success.

Comment: Please see the **Isolating The Error** note that I just added to the end of the OP.  The `NonSerializableException` can be turned on and then turned off again by `project.getItems()`.

Comment: Updated with a full script using node/stage and a`@NonCPS` method to avoid complaints about using `.each`. I think we're both using scripted pipelines, but there's possibly some other configuration discrepancy that's causing it to work for me but not for you.

Comment: Your update brings this very close to being resolved, I hope.  My remaining problem is that `http://<jenkins-home>/scriptApproval` does not seem to allow me to add the other objects to the whitelist.  I cannot paste them, and it is not autopopulating them into an approval list.

Comment: I had to run the build six times, each failing on a single `RejectedAccessException` with a console message along the lines of: `Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.` The "Administrators can decide" message is a link; I would then manually click the **Approve** button for each one (I am an administrator on the Jenkins instance).

Comment: I am the administrator of this Jenkins instance.  The link worked for the first object on your list.  Thank you for reminding me.  But now the link from the `BUILD FAILED: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.ItemGroup getItems` error message does not work for the other objects.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't be adding the new blocked method to the `scriptApproval` list for each failure. My experience is that each build will add a single new exception that has to be approved.

Comment: I added two screen shots to the end of the OP, which together illustrate the problems that Jenkins is giving when I need to whitelist the commands that you listed in your answer.  I am not sure how to address this.  Not sure if I should ask a separate question about whitelisting.  I do not want to keep hounding you when you have already invested a lot of your time.  But yet the new screen shots indicate that I am not able to implement your answer in my system yet.  What do you think?

Comment: Let's try an end-around: Go to `http://<jenkins-home>/script`. Copy/paste in the `getBranchNames` method (without `@NonCPS`). Then add a line: `getBranchNames(jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("YOUR_PROJECT_NAME"))`. Then **Run**. It should fail with the script permission error, but it _should_ add it to the list to allow approval.

Comment: I just added the results of your most recent suggestion to a new section at the end of the OP entitled **Another attempt to whitelist**.  What do you suggest?

Comment: Sorry, trying to do too many things at once. Change the `echo` to `println`

Comment: Changing `echo` to `println` caused the script to successfully print a list of project branches in `http://<jenkins-home>/script/`, but still nothing was added to the approval queue at `http://<jenkins-home>/scriptApproval/`, and still the project branch throws the same failure when I re-run the most recent job.

Comment: Finally got around to testing this from scratch. I think the reason the new approvals don't appear is because of the try/catch block. The `catch` must be changing the behavior in such a way that the new signature isn't added to the scriptApproval list. Try to remove the try/catch and see if, after it fails, the new signature appears in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the available Jenkins API to get the list of branches/Jobs under any pipeline:
Syntax: ${Base_Url}/api/json?tree=jobs[name]