# list ALL jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I try to use a groovy script to list all Jenkins jobs on a server but it fails to get the jobs that are inside multibranch pipelines. I am only able to get the "freestyle projects".

I use `Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractProject.class)` but what I understand from the documentation is that, it will list all jobs implementing the `AbstractProject` class, which is not the case for the multibranch pipelines. Is there another way to proceed to get those jobs?

The ultimate goal is that sometimes, I want to launch all jobs in a folder. That folder contains over 100 multibranch pipeline with a few branches each. I don't want to trigger each one individually as it would be very time consuming.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're looking for this: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226941767-Groovy-to-list-all-jobs

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. As explained in the question, I tried exactly that but it does not return the jobs inside multibranch pipelines, which are exactly the ones I want.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing to create an extensible choice parameter listing multibranch jobs. So here's what I came up with based on this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50163644

```
def getBranchNames(project){
    project.getItems().each { job ->
        println(job.getProperty(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.BranchJobProperty.class).getBranch().getName())
    }
}
getBranchNames(jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("/multibranch-job-name"))
```

Hope this helps the next person.